# MySQL - Error #1193 - Unknown system variable 'FETCH_STATUS'

Tags: mysql

I having above error while creating process while creating following stored procedure. Please help me to solve this problem.Definition of stored procedure is given below. Thank in advance

Here is my code

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS 

`sp_rpt_process_status`$$


CREATE DEFINER=`saumitra`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_rpt_process_status`()
BEGIN

DECLARE reqs_id INT(11);
DECLARE app_id INT(11);
DECLARE ap_name varchar(100);

declare cur CURSOR for
    select table_id from aerion.rpt_process where table_update='dev_est_reqs';

open cur;

fetch next from cur into reqs_id;

while     @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    SELECT iddev_est INTO est_id, iddev_apps INTO app_id from aerion.dev_est where iddev_est_reqs=reqs_id;
    SELECT app_name INTO ap_name FROM dev_apps WHERE iddev_apps=app_id;
    INSERT INTO `rpt_dev_status`(`rpt_dev_app`) VALUES (ap_name); 
    fetch next from cur into reqs_id;

END

close cur
deallocate cur

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I hope you are not trying to use SQL server code on MySQL. `@@FETCH_STATUS` is not supported by MySQL. Here's a link on how to convert to MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871926/how-to-convert-a-sql-server-cursor-to-mysql-equivalent