# MySQL Trigger Problems

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi guys I have some problems with my MySQL trigger, I need my trigger tell me if the ingredients are in the cursor ingredientesMenu are also in the ingredientesPaciente cursor.
As it comes to knowing whether a patient can eat the ingredients of a menu depending on the ingredients that he can eat.
The problem is that, for any menu that you enter the trigger tells me that contains ingredients that the patient can not eat.

P.D.: Srry for the bad English.

```
drop trigger comidaAdecuada;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER comidaAdecuada
BEFORE INSERT ON PACIENTE_COME
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE menuIngrediente INT;
    DECLARE aux INT;
    DECLARE cantidadI INT;
    DECLARE sVariable INT;

    DECLARE ingredientesMenu CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id_ingrediente
        FROM COMIDA_INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN MENU_COMIDA
        WHERE id_menu = NEW.id_menu;

    DECLARE cantidadIngredientes CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT cantidad
        FROM INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN COMIDA_INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN MENU_COMIDA
        WHERE id_menu = NEW.id_menu;

    DECLARE ingredientesPaciente CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id_ingrediente
        FROM INGREDIENTE_ENFERMEDAD NATURAL JOIN PACIENTE_ENFERMEDAD
        WHERE dni_paciente = NEW.dni_paciente;

    OPEN ingredientesMenu;
    OPEN ingredientesPaciente;
    OPEN cantidadIngredientes;

    FETCH NEXT FROM ingredientesMenu INTO menuIngrediente;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cantidadIngredientes INTO cantidadI;

    read_loop: WHILE (FETCH_STATUS = 0) DO

        IF(cantidadI = 0) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No quedan ingredientes para el menú proporcionado';
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET aux = (SELECT id_ingrediente FROM ingredientesPaciente WHERE id_ingrediente = menuIngrediente);

        IF(aux = menuIngrediente) THEN
            SET sVariable = 0;
        ELSE
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Se ha detectado un ingrediente no adecuado para el paciente en el menú propuesto.';
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        FETCH NEXT FROM ingredientesMenu INTO menuIngrediente;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cantidadIngredientes INTO cantidadI;

    END WHILE;

    CLOSE ingredientesMenu;
    CLOSE ingredientesPaciente;
    CLOSE cantidadIngredientes;

END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

---

Ok, I changed the code and syntax no longer has problems, but still does not do what I like.

Now always inserted, even though the ingredients are not good for the patient.

New Code:

```
drop trigger comidaAdecuada;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER comidaAdecuada
BEFORE INSERT ON PACIENTE_COME
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    DECLARE menuIngrediente INT;
    DECLARE aux INT;
    DECLARE cantidadI INT;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE ingredientesMenu CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id_ingrediente
        FROM COMIDA_INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN MENU_COMIDA
        WHERE id_menu = NEW.id_menu;

    DECLARE cantidadIngredientes CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT cantidad
        FROM INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN COMIDA_INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN MENU_COMIDA
        WHERE id_menu = NEW.id_menu;

    DECLARE ingredientesPaciente CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT id_ingrediente
        FROM INGREDIENTE_ENFERMEDAD NATURAL JOIN PACIENTE_ENFERMEDAD
        WHERE dni_paciente = NEW.dni_paciente;


    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN ingredientesMenu;
    OPEN ingredientesPaciente;
    OPEN cantidadIngredientes;

    FETCH NEXT FROM ingredientesMenu INTO menuIngrediente;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cantidadIngredientes INTO cantidadI;

    read_loop: LOOP

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF(cantidadI = 0) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No quedan ingredientes para el menú proporcionado';
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET aux = (SELECT id_ingrediente FROM ingredientesPaciente WHERE id_ingrediente = menuIngrediente);

        IF(aux <> menuIngrediente) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Se ha detectado un ingrediente no adecuado para el paciente en el menú propuesto.';
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        FETCH NEXT FROM ingredientesMenu INTO menuIngrediente;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cantidadIngredientes INTO cantidadI;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE ingredientesMenu;
    CLOSE ingredientesPaciente;
    CLOSE cantidadIngredientes;

END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

Special thanks to Uueerdo for the help.

---

I solve my problem, I have some problems with CURSOR but now the code is OK.

```
drop trigger comidaAdecuada;

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER comidaAdecuada
BEFORE INSERT ON PACIENTE_COME
FOR EACH ROW
trigger_label: BEGIN

    DECLARE menuIngrediente INT;
    DECLARE aux INT;
    DECLARE cantidadI INT;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE numeroIngredientes INT;
    DECLARE cantidadIngredientes INT;

    DECLARE ingredientesMenu CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT id_ingrediente
        FROM COMIDA_INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN MENU_COMIDA
        WHERE id_menu = NEW.id_menu;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET numeroIngredientes = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM INGREDIENTE
                            WHERE id_ingrediente IN (
                                SELECT DISTINCT id_ingrediente
                                FROM INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN COMIDA_INGREDIENTE
                                WHERE id_comida IN (
                                    SELECT id_comida
                                    FROM COMIDA_INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN MENU_COMIDA
                                    WHERE id_menu = NEW.id_menu
                                    )));

    SET cantidadIngredientes = (SELECT COUNT(*)
                            FROM INGREDIENTE
                            WHERE id_ingrediente IN (
                                SELECT DISTINCT id_ingrediente
                                FROM INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN COMIDA_INGREDIENTE
                                WHERE INGREDIENTE.cantidad > 0 AND id_comida IN (
                                    SELECT id_comida
                                    FROM COMIDA_INGREDIENTE NATURAL JOIN MENU_COMIDA
                                    WHERE id_menu = NEW.id_menu
                                    )));

    IF(cantidadIngredientes <> numeroIngredientes) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'No quedan ingredientes para el menú proporcionado';
        LEAVE trigger_label;
    END IF;

    OPEN ingredientesMenu;

    read_loop: LOOP

        FETCH NEXT FROM ingredientesMenu INTO menuIngrediente;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SET aux = (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM
                        (SELECT DISTINCT id_ingrediente
                        FROM INGREDIENTE_ENFERMEDAD NATURAL JOIN PACIENTE_ENFERMEDAD
                        WHERE dni_paciente = NEW.dni_paciente) INGREDIENTES_PACIENTE
                    WHERE INGREDIENTES_PACIENTE.id_ingrediente = menuIngrediente);

        IF(aux < 1) THEN
            SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Se ha detectado un ingrediente no adecuado para el paciente en el menú propuesto.';
            LEAVE trigger_label;
        END IF;

        SET aux = 0;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE ingredientesMenu;
END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to comment that way, just edit the question. Also, You shouldn't need to have that kind of "no op" in the `IF` just do `IF aux <> menuIngrediente THEN SIGNAL.... END IF;`

Comment: FETCH STATUS is not in MySQL as far as I know, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871926/how-to-convert-a-sql-server-cursor-to-mysql-equivalent) might help you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about your logic. I am just guessing, but you may need to have separate loops; right now you will only be processing as many results as the shortest result set. (If either has 0 results, nothing at all will be processed.)